# Duda con moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Tengo una duda respecto al uso de moment.js , la cuestión es, si yo hoy pongo una fecha y hora por ejemplo 14/03/2018 a la 01:00, tengo por costumbre guardar la hora UTC en base de datos para luego formatearla a la fecha/hora que corresponda dependiendo de la región del cliente (de ahí el uso de moment), hasta aquí bien, pero tengo un problema, el cual es, en lugar de ser hoy, por ejemplo lo pongo en agosto (que hay un horario distinto) pues no veo bien la hora, hasta que no tenga ese tipo de horario, cambia de +1 a +2 horas dependiendo de la época del año.

Entonces mi pregunta es, si yo quiero fijar una fecha hora, por ejemplo 14/08/2018 a la 1, quiero ver la 1, esté en marzo o en agosto, pero no entiendo muy bien como se ha de hacer esto.

Espero cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo del formato en que tienes guardada la fecha y el código donde la procesas usando `momentjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica que al hacer hacer el formato con moment toma como `default` el **timezone** de Estados Unidos, entonces cambia el horario. Para evitar eso, es cuestión de cambiar el timezone de **moment.js** agregando la librería de [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

**Por ejemplo:**

```
moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "Europe/London");
// Europe/London: 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
// America/New_York: 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación!

Answer (score 2):

No se como es que haces el cambio de hora `utc` a `local time` pero esto se hace con el `time zone`, no se si **moment.js** hace esto de manera interna porque no lo he usado pero siempre puedes hacerlo tu mismo con el objeto date de javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset(); // te entrega el offset en minutos (+2 = 120)
```

Ahora el timezone sabe cuando es el cambio de hora, si le preguntas el offset el 13 de agosto a las 23:59 te dirá por ejemplo +1 (60) y si lo haces el 14 de agosto a las 00:00 te dirá +2 (120).

Espero esto te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación!